# Perl Mime Problem

Tags: perl

I m newbie at perl.I'm trying to use Mime::Lite.I looked their site
and i try to sending mail this way

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From     =>'cassidy@hotmail.com',
    To       =>'ericafb77@gmail.com',
    Cc       =>'some@other.com, some@more.com',
    Subject  =>'Helloooooo, nurse!',
    Data     =>"AAA"
);
$msg->send;
```

But mail did not come to my mail adress.What should i do?

Comment: "What should I do?" -- start debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform?

On a well-configured Linux/UNIX box this usually works as is, but if you're using Windows, you probably need to tell it how to send the mail.

The following should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From => 'me@example.com',
    To => 'you@example.com',
    Cc => 'her@example.com,him@example.com',
    Subject => 'Hello, World!',
    Data => 'Test.',
);
$msg->send(smtp => 'smtp.example.com');
```

where `smtp.example.com` is the SMTP server that your internet provider tells you to use.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify that your host actually sent the E-mail using SMTP by using a packet sniffer such as [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) ? If not, do that and report your findings here.